# Moodle setup: Error code: missingconfigversion

Tags: postgresql, moodle

I am trying to set up my moodle site using postgresSQL locally. I am receiving this error after setup:

```
Config table does not contain version, can not continue, sorry.

More information about this error

It is usually not possible to recover from errors triggered during installation, you may need to create a new database or use a different database prefix if you want to retry the installation.

×Debug info:
Error code: missingconfigversion
×Stack trace:
line 495 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 287 of /admin/index.php: call to print_error()
```

The correct version IS in the database table `mdl_config`. I have also deleted the database and recreated it twice which seems to be the only advice I can find anywhere.

I have all the debugging settings turned on and am not receiving any more information.

Are there any other solutions to fixing this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is there then it might be a database permission or the wrong database.

Maybe check the owner of `mdl_config` is the same as the `$CFG->dbuser` value in `config.php`

Also double check `$CFG->dbname` is the correct database name.

I use postgresql most of the time. These are the typical values in config.php

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'pgsql';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'mydatabasename';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'mydatabaseuser';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'xxxxx';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
);
```

Comment: Hi Russell, thanks for your response. I have checked again and yes, the user owns the entire database and the dbname is correct. I changed dbhost from 10.0.2.2 to localhost but I am not getting the error "Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host 'localhost' (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in [dirroot]/lib/dml/pgsql_native_moodle_database.php on line 159"